# Walkthrough Q&A

Tags: support

Is there an easy way to find answers that are step-by-step walkthroughs to a question?

Here's an example of what I mean by step-by-step walkthroughs:

- [how-to-get-a-miniature-effect-on-pictures-without-special-equipment](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15929/how-to-get-a-miniature-effect-on-pictures-without-special-equipment/15934#15934)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this is something we could do for the blog - reword some of the best walkthrough answers into articles (I saw reword, as the question wouldn't be there)

Answer (score 2):

From my experience here (and other SE sites that may have step-by-step walk through) you just have to search for what you are looking for and see if someone has provided a step by step guide. You can always comment and ask the person answering to explain a bit more or to provide steps or you can ask the question yourself (granted that it is on topic and not a duplicate) and ask for someone to provide step by step instructions as a part of the answer.

*Edit:* Per my question [here](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2266/tagging-answers) and the [answer](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2266/tagging-answers#answer-2267) provided you can do a [search](https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?q=is:answer%20walkthrough) with the following: `is:answer walkthrough`  though for this to be effective for searching keywords would need to be added.

Answer (score 2):

Why not have a new tag? As we find existing answers add the step-by-step tag to those that warrent it?