# Tagging Answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, answers

After reading this question: [Walkthrough Q&A](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2264/walkthrough-qa/) - I was thinking about it some and had an idea (for what it's worth => )

Currently we tag questions based on certain topics and overall it works great. I believe it could be beneficial to be able to provide tags to answers as well. The tags would not be the same as the questions tags. The idea is you can tag your answer as to a type of answer. The answers then could be tagged as `walk-through` or `step-by-step` or something similar.

This is just an idea and needs more thought and input if even to be remotely considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feels like it would be really useful in a handful of scenarios (like this one) and confusing or distracting the rest of the time.

And... Frankly, it's hard enough to get a decent set of tags used consistently on *questions* - if you wanted this to work, you'd probably end up having to go through all the questions and re-tag walk-through answers yourself...

If you were gonna do that, you could just as well edit in a keyword and [search for it](https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+walkthrough) if you wanted it in the future. This is probably an easier format to train folks to follow anyway, and avoids adding further complexity to the system

Comment: I must agree =>

Comment: "you could just as well edit in a keyword" -- isn't that *precisely* what tags are for?

Comment: @drewbenn: not... *exactly.* Tags generally *are* keywords, but there are plenty of keywords that aren't appropriate for, or never make it into tags, which are primarily an *organizational* tool